# Validating time with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, client-side-validation

I'm trying to validate a Time field with jQuery. Basically, what I want to do is only allow people to enter times after 18:00.
I realise that I can do this with the standard HTML5 field validation, but with jQuery, it's so much easier to format the response to the user, and the rest of the form is already jQuery validated.

Thanks...

Colin

Comment: http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery time picker

A javascript solution can be like

```
<script>
function validate_time(t,st,et){
   t = t.split(/:/);
   st = st.split(/:/);
   et = et.split(/:/);
   return (t[0] < st[0] 
        || t[0] > et[0] 
        || (t[0] == st[0] && t[1] < st[1])
        || (t[0] == et[0] && t[1] > et[1]));
}

     // Call like:
     validate_time("08:00","07:00","15:00");

     //validate_time(UserEnteredTime,ValidTimeStart,ValidTimeEnd);

</script>
```

For JS solution, thanks to [cmptrgeekken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151826/validate-time-in-range)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

**Use jQuery Time Picker**

http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/
& write below code

```
$('#durationExample').timepicker({
'minTime': '2:00pm',
'maxTime': '11:30pm',
'showDuration': true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to work with date time validation a lot I suggest you to use [Moment.JS](https://github.com/moment/moment) . You can extract "hour" easily and check if it's greater than 18:00. It can also validate date and time if it's a editable user input.